# Detecting whether user is standing or sitting

Tags: java, android, activity-recognition

I want to predict a standing to sitting transition and vice versa of a user in Android. But I guess, currently Google's DetectedActivity Api gives everything but sitting-standing transition. What are the other ways of doing this? Also, I have tried gathering the accelerometer values, but don't know how to get a pattern from the values and then later predict transitions using that pattern. So how should I proceed?

Comment: You can try something like this [link](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs65/lecture22/lecture22.html)

Answer (score 2):

[According to the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity#constants):

> public static final int TILTING
>
> The device angle relative to gravity changed significantly. This often occurs when a device is picked up from a desk or **a user who is sitting stands up**.

I have highlighted the key phrase. This would appear to be the answer you seek.

Comment: Yeah actually I tried that as well, but I think manipulating the tilt values won't be that much reliable.
So I am looking for some kind of pattern matching. Is there any way to do that?